# SQL server 2005 is dropping connections

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, windows-server-2008, connection-pooling, database-administration

We have newly purchased Windows web server 2008 r2. We have installed SQL server 2005 Express and IIS 7 on this server for running our websites.

We have observed that connections are dropping or not available frequently. If I logged in to my computer and run my website it works. However, if nobody uses the server / application for a while the 1<sup>st</sup> subsequent request usually fails with the error "invalid connection attribute or connection time out".

I have checked:

1. The number of connections connected (application using database) to database found not more than 4 which varies accordingly.
2. I have tried to unblock the firewall but failed.
3. I don't have any anti-virus software installed so there shouldn't be any conflicts there.

I was trying to create an ODBC connection for which I have opened port 1433 and enabled all settings required from the management configuration. However, I am not able to access port 1433.

What else can I do to diagnose the root issue(s)?

Comment: This seems like more of a question for ServerFault.

Comment: thanks i have solved the issue , using odbc driver